# Cannot parse KML file using OSMBonusPack library

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am trying to write a simple Android application using Osmdroid and Osmdroidbonuspack but I am having problems getting past the first stages, following the basic examples in their tutorials.

I am able to display a map using osmdroid, but when I try to parse a url using osmdroidbonuspack, the parser always returns false.

The URL I used is the "Paris tour" one from this tutorial:
http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3

and I know the file exists as the link works.

The code in my main activity is:

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setZoom(2);

    KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    boolean ok = kmlDocument.parseUrl("http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=z6IJfj90QEd4.kUUY9FoHFRdE");
```

I should add, I noticed some networking related errors in logcat:

```
02-13 23:28:28.177: W/System.err(1652): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-13 23:28:28.181: W/System.err(1652):     at    android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
02-13 23:28:28.181: W/System.err(1652):     at     java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-13 23:28:28.185: W/System.err(1652):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-13 23:28:28.185: W/System.err(1652):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-13 23:28:28.185: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-13 23:28:28.185: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-13 23:28:28.189: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-13 23:28:28.189: W/System.err(1652):     at    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-13 23:28:28.189: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-13 23:28:28.193: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-13 23:28:28.193: W/System.err(1652):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-13 23:28:28.193: W/System.err(1652):     at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.HttpConnection.doGet(HttpConnection.java:75)
02-13 23:28:28.197: W/System.err(1652):     at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlDocument.parseUrl(KmlDocument.java:231)
02-13 23:28:28.197: W/System.err(1652):     at com.example.testosmdroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-13 23:28:28.197: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-13 23:28:28.197: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-13 23:28:28.201: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-13 23:28:28.201: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-13 23:28:28.201: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-13 23:28:28.201: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-13 23:28:28.205: W/System.err(1652):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 23:28:28.205: W/System.err(1652):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 23:28:28.205: W/System.err(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-13 23:28:28.209: W/System.err(1652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 23:28:28.209: W/System.err(1652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 23:28:28.209: W/System.err(1652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-13 23:28:28.213: W/System.err(1652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-13 23:28:28.213: W/System.err(1652):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error in MainActivity occurs at the parseUrl line.
When I saw this I thought it might be due to a permissions issue but I just checked and it seems I have all of the required permissions, at least according to this tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/Prerequisites

My AndroidManifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testosmdroid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alight, going back and reading some more documentation I have answered my own question. From one of their other tutorials:

> For clarity and simplicity, in these tutorials, we do all API calls in the main thread.
>
> Normally, for network calls, this is not recommended at all: we should use threads and asynchronous tasks. Even worst, since Honeycomb SDK (3.0), it is not allowed to make a network call in the main thread (thanks to the "StrictMode.ThreadPolicy" default settings, a NetworkOnMainThreadException exception will be raised).
>
> So:
>       For these tutorials, target an SDK earlier than 3.0
>       Once you have played with the tutos and want to work on your real app, have a look at the OSMBonusPackDemo source code, where network calls are done in async tasks.

After following their advice it now parses correctly.